# How can i add activity history to salesforce?

Tags: rest-api, activityhistory

I'm trying to export some call, email activity history to sales force. How can i achieve this?

[Activity History Doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_activityhistory.htm) says that its a non editable fields. Is there any other way to do this? Using their api.

Answer (score 4):

ActivityHistory is a type of "view" object: it shows closed tasks and events that are in the past. To add new entries, simply create new [Task](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_task.htm) or [Event](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_event.htm) objects. Uusally, calls and emails are logged as tasks with a "Completed" status (the default value). You can use the Data Loader, Excel Connector, the REST, SOAP, or Bulk API, etc.

Comment: The OP has clear tags referred to REST API, not through SFDC UI

Comment: @estebanrincon Yes, you can create tasks and events through the SOAP, REST, and Bulk APIs; there's no specific reference to the UI in this answer.

Comment: yes sorry missread your answer. Do you know if there's a possibility to create a custom connector for Pardot?

Comment: @estebanrincon I'm not qualified to answer that question. I would suggest posting a new question; it's likely someone here can help you.